# Change pin label in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I change the label for pins in an embedded google maps?

Ive figured out how to change the marker to my icon, but I need to restyle the A, B, C etc similar to how travelodge do for there map http://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/book/edinburgh-hotels

UPDATE this is the code that successfully uses a custom marker:

```
  function addMarker(latlng, myTitle) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map,
            title: myTitle,
            icon: "www.linkto/myPin.png" 
          }));
    }
```

Ive included markerwithlabel.js However this doesn't create any markers at all:

```
  function addMarker(latlng, myTitle) {
        markers.push(new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map,
            title: myTitle,
            icon: "www.linkto/myPin.png",

            labelContent: "$425K",
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
            labelClass: "labels", 
            labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

          }));
    }
```

This is the code I was tying to adapt: 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/basic.html

Answer (score 4):

If you managed to change the marker icon, then you **did all the work**.

A marker does not have a label. What travelodge does is that it has markers for each letter and then sets them according to the search results.

**EDIT:**

It seems there's a special library to do what you want (go to "Styled Marker"):

http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel

To see the code click in "Development versions", then "Examples" and then look at the source code of the pages. Here's the Simple example code:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.313477473067, -121.880502070713);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  var styleMaker2 = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE,{color:"ff0000",text:"I'm a marker!"}),position:new google.maps.LatLng(37.383477473067, -121.880502070713),map:map});
  var styleMaker1 = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"00ff00",text:"A"}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
  var styleMaker3 = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"0000ff"}),position:new google.maps.LatLng(37.263477473067, -121.880502070713),map:map});
}
```

You can read more about markers on [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)

Comment: Are you sure? From looking at their site I can see the pin and the label are separate images.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Ive tried using the code from the example and updated by question but its not working. Thanks